# Excel VBA to change a cell value depending on multiple selection throughout the sheet

Tags: excel, vba, drop-down-menu, dependencies

I have a cell (C25) at the bottom of a sheet that I want to either display "Yes" or "No" to the question "Requires Approval?" I suppose No would be the default.

Basically users are going to answer a series of questions using dropdowns throughout the form and depending on these selections it will tell them whether or not they require approval. The triggers are certain choices from 5 dropdown lists. Precisely, 2 options from dropdown 1 (C4) trigger a Yes, the other 10 choices do not (No). 1 option from dropdown 2 (C11) triggers a yes, the other do not and so on.

Additionally, if the user makes any selection that triggers a Yes, it must stay as a Yes. For example if they answer one dropdown that triggers a Yes and then answer another that does not, it should not set it to No, but if no value that triggers a Yes is selected anymore (for example, they change their mind and change the first dropdown selection), it should set it to No.

I have no idea how to go about writing the code for this. I'm using 64-bit Excel 2013 if that's any help.

Answer (score 0):

you could create a Worksheet_Change event and handle the cells that have dropdowns

example

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$C$4" And Target = "value" Then
        Cells(25, 3) = "Yes"
    End If
End Sub
```

And if you have No as the default for C25, you don't need code for it